c# JWT token Creation Then token validation returning error
Im creating a web app that does auth through JWT tokens. Within my web assembly I make calls to my web api to create/validate my tokens.
I create my tokens like this:
public string GenerateJwtToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims, DateTime expireAt)
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Value.Key));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: jwtSettings.Value.Issuer,
            audience: jwtSettings.Value.Audience,
            claims: claims, 
            expires: expireAt, 
            signingCredentials: creds);
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }

and validate them with this function:
public ClaimsPrincipal? ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Value.Key));
        try
        {
            var tokenValidation = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = key,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.Value.Issuer,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = jwtSettings.Value.Audience,
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
            SecurityToken validateToken;
            var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidation, out validateToken);
            return principal;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

However when I create a token and set the expiresAt at : DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30) then validate my token I get an error of:
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenNoExpirationException: IDX10225: Lifetime validation failed.

Does anyone know why? my jwt settings get injected and set correctly as well.

What version of .NET are you using? I'm unable to reproduce the same error when using .NET 8 and System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt v7.61

im using .net 8 with System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt  v7.1.2

ive updated my System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to the latest version and im not getting the same error so that's progress haha

it was mainly the version I think as now I can get some kind of response
